# Adding further variable to until command

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I have the following command which works ok but I would like to add a further variable in somehow:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=40000
until [ $x = "180000" ]; do
        dd bs=1 if=static.file of=extracted${x}.file skip=12345 count=$x;
        first_ten=$(hexdump -e '1/1 "%.2X"' "extracted${x}.file" | head -c 10);
                if [ "$first_ten" == "1234567890" ]
                then
                echo "${x}" >> correct.txt;
                fi;
        rm extracted${x}.file;
    ((x++))
done
```

I would like to add in an incremental variable to the skip section so once it's completed the 'x' variable to then increment the (skip) 'y' variable by 1 and start the process over.

```
#!/bin/bash
y=12345
x=40000
until [ $x = "180000" ]; do
        dd bs=1 if=static.file of=extracted${x}.file skip=$x count=$x;
        first_ten=$(hexdump -e '1/1 "%.2X"' "extracted${x}.file" | head -c 10);
                if [ "$first_ten" == "1234567890" ]
                then
                echo "${y}_${x}" >> correct.txt;
                fi;
        rm extracted${x}.file;
    ((x++))
done
```

Just not totally sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `for` loops i.e. one for `y` and one for `x` (or `while`/`until` in the `y`'s loop i.e. the outer loop):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
for ((y=0; y<12345; y++)); do
    for ((x=40000; x<180000; x++)); do
        dd bs=1 if=static.file of=extracted${x}.file skip=12345 count=$x;
        first_ten=$(hexdump -e '1/1 "%.2X"' "extracted${x}.file" | head -c 10);
                if [ "$first_ten" == "1234567890" ]
                then
                echo "${x}" >> correct.txt;
                fi;
        rm extracted${x}.file;
    done
done
```

Change the values to meet your need.

**Example:**

```
% cat scr.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for ((y=0; y<=3; y++)); do
    for ((x=0; x<=2; x++)); do
        echo "This is $x : $y"
    done
done

% ./scr.sh  
This is 0 : 0
This is 1 : 0
This is 2 : 0
This is 0 : 1
This is 1 : 1
This is 2 : 1
This is 0 : 2
This is 1 : 2
This is 2 : 2
This is 0 : 3
This is 1 : 3
This is 2 : 3
```

Comment: It doesn't increment the y, at the end of the first specified 'y' number run of 'x' it halts without going to the next iteration of 'y'.

Comment: @th3joker It starts `y` at 0, then exhaust one run of `x` (from 40000 to 180000) and increment `y` by 1 and do the `x` operation again, then increment `y` by 1 again....this loop continues until `y` is exhausted i.e. `y` become 12345....It's not what you want?

Comment: it is but it doesn't do that, after it exhausts x on the first round of y it stops.

Comment: also 'y' is the variable for skip, so skip should read:
    skip=$y

Comment: @th3joker my bad..fixed..

Comment: an outer `while` loop for y would work too

Comment: @Xen2050 Thats correct..

Comment: Oops, I mean `until`. Maybe easier for the OP to stick another until loop around their code...?

Comment: @Xen2050 It's the same thing :) Right....

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to test both variables use && operator and another test

```
until [ $x  -eq 180000" ] && [ $y -eq  9999 ]; do
```

Comment: I want it to do 'x' the specified number of times and then increment 'y' by 1 then complete 'x' again.

Comment: Hmmm, you could use an extra counter variable, but i think it would be possible with modulo operator as well. I'll edit when I've time. It's hard to post answers using phone